# How to ignore unknown config on .net configuration manager

Tags: .net, visual-c++, configuration

I have a .net application configured with .net configuration manager user configuration. The same config file is shared with another C++ application because these applications share the most of configurations. The problem is that whenever I add a configuration element for the C++ application, it breaks .net one. Is there any way to make .net configuration manager ignore unknown configuration elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that .net does not use and consider valid options used by c++. You are better off splitting the two projects into two config files for just the sort of problems that you are seeing now.

Comment: So what was wrong with the answer? C++ and managed code does not have a lot in common, so why te downgrade?